# How to update and display a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I work in a warehouse. I'm helping a supervisor by making a proof of concept program that will allow him to update what truck is in what dock door at any given time.
I made a table to display the doors and the trailer numbers. each row has an input field to enter the new trailer number, and a submit button that when clicked should save the new trailer number to a variable, then display said variable in the table. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong, please help!

```
<script>
    var 1s = "open", 2s = "open", 3s = "open", 4s = "open" 5s = "open", 1n = "open", 2n = "open", 3n = "open", 4n = "open", 5n = "open";

    function display1s(){
        1s = document.getElementById("1sInput");
        document.getElementById("1s").innerHTML = 1s.innerhtml;
        }
</script>

<body>

<table border=3>
    <tr>
        <th>Door #</th>
        <th>Trailer #</th>
        <th>input new trailer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1S</td>
        <td><p id="1s"></p></td>
        <td><input type="input" name=1sInput size=14></td>
        <td><button onClick="katie()">Submit</button></td> 
    </tr>
```

updated! I removed code that wasn't necessary. To be more specific, what I am trying to do is have a user input a string into the input box id'd as 1sInput, save that string to the variable 1s, then display it in the

tag id'd as 1s. I am very much new to programming. I know this is probably a super simple question but for the life of me I cannot find the answer in any book that I own or any online tutorial.

Comment: java is to javascript as ham is to hamster, please do not add the java tag for your javascript question =)

Comment: I don't see any form that will handle the submit. What are you trying to accomplish? And if you're working with Java or other server side technology, please provide the relevant code in the server that will process the form submission (if any).

Comment: @Nizil the question is too vague so I don't know if the question is even about javascript, for me seems like OP has lots of concepts to understand. Probably he/she works with Java as well but doesn't know how to tie it correctly to the view.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I totally agree with you, expect I don't think OP works with a backend currently. Because as you said, he have a lots of concepts to understand before being able to create a fullstack application ^^ Moreover, I suspect OP provided his whole code.

Comment: I apologize. I am working with javascript/html. There is no server. basically what I am trying to do is create an html document that will allow a user to enter a string, click submit, and have that string display in a table. So using an example from my code, a user would enter 12345 into the input box id'd as 1sinput, then click submit, and that string (12345) should be saved to the variable 1s, and displayed in the <p> tag id'd as 1s. also, if this has been answered elsewhere or there is a tutorial someone can point me to I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function katie(){
        var _1s = document.getElementsByName("1sinput")[0];
        document.getElementById("1s").innerHTML = _1s.value;
        }
</script>
```

That is how example code can be made runnable. Take notice that you can't start variable names with numericals in javascript. I guess you're new to JS development, and JS error console is your best friend.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to JS. That explains one of the errors I was getting. This makes sense. Thank you thank you thank you. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: You may use built-in debugger to correct and detect errors. Just press ctrl+shift+k to open debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the problem, what's wrong with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border=3>
  <tr>
    <th>Door #</th>
    <th>Trailer #</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1S</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```